# its vs. their in the following example

Tags: pronouns, possessives

I am not sure whether the possessive pronoun can refer to the plural noun or only to the singular noun in the following example:

> Clarity on the non-identity between the underlying algorithms and
> ***their/its*** consequences for the results is supposed to provide a good
> basis.

Does the possessive pronoun have to refer to *clarity* (its) because of the sentence structure or can it also refer to the *algorithms* (their)? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this your own sentence or have you found it somewhere? If the latter is true, please provide the link. If it is your own sentence, state what you want it to mean.

Comment: 'Their' **must** refer to 'underlying algorithms' here (_singular they_ and _singular their_ only come into play when used to avoid gender specificity, as in 'the murderer left their ring at the scene of the crime'). And I don't think this makes sense. But you don't give full context. 'Clarity on the non-identity between the underlying algorithms, and on the effect on the results caused by this non-identity, is supposed ....' is more accurate if more prolix.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is my sentence and I shortened it, the full sentence is actually: "Clarity on the non-identity between the underlying algorithms and its consequences for the results is supposed to provide a basis for a methodological discussion about which method and which variants thereof are more successful in deriving which search target."

Comment: What I want to say is that by clearly showing the non-identity between algorithm A and B and by explaining which consequences this non-identity has on the results that method X and Y (based on algorithms A and B) produce I want to enable an informed discussion about which method is more successful in deriving which search target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the possessive pronoun have to refer to clarity (its) because of the sentence structure or can it also refer to the algorithms (their)?

If the pronoun used is *its* then it most probably refers back to *Clarity*. It doesn't have to refer to *Clarity* but since *Clarity* is the subject of the main verb phrase, the cascading prepositional phrases *on the non-identity* / *between the underlying algorithms* are subordinated, and this leaves *its* as almost certainly having *Clarity* as its antecedent.

If the pronoun used is *their* then it most probably refers back to *algorithms*. That usage would not be difficult for the reader to comprehend.